# How to import .XML code style into IntelliJ Idea 15

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, intellij-15

I want to use a specific code style in my editor defined in an XML file, which looks something like this:

```
<code_scheme name="CustomStyleName">
<option name="JAVA_INDENT_OPTIONS">
<value>
...
```

How is it possible to import this style into IntelliJ Idea.
When I go to Preferences->Editor->Code Style->Manage it is only possible to import an Eclipse XML Profile.

[image: screenshot of the import dialog]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If your XML is previously exported Intellij you can simply do:

> File > Import Settings > select your xml

If its custom defined, one you can try copying your xml to intellij config directory:

> config/codestyles

Assuming your xml is in format intellij can understand, it will then show up in

> Code Styles > Manage

If your XML is in different format, try to match tags with one of pre-defined styles(also XML)

Comment: Copying it to the config/codestyles directory (I created it first) and restarting the IDE solved it.

Comment: The location on OSX: ~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC15/codestyles

Comment: The location on Linux: `~/.<PRODUCT><VERSION>/config/codestyles`

Comment: For me in OSX it is a little bit different: `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea15/codestyles/ `

Comment: For Windows with IDEA14, it is in `~\.IntelliJIdea14\config\codestyles`

Answer (score 17):

For users coming here for the same issue but recent IntelliJ version (like 20), it is a bit different now. 
Once you've exported your formatter in XML, then follow these steps:

1. Go to **Preferences**
2. Select **Editor**
3. Sele **Code Style**
4. Select the language of your choice (eg Java)
5. Go to **Scheme** at the top, click on the setting button by the side
6. Select the option to import scheme, choose your formatter type and select the xml file. Then save and apply.

[image]

If you see error "*IntelliJ IDEA code style XML import failed with error message: null*", check to ensure your XML file has the file definition `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the top.

**NOTE**: This is for MacBook. I believe the difference won't be much in other platforms.

Comment: Do you know how to compare if current coding scheme and one which we are importing have any difference ?

Comment: I haven't done that, but I'll suggest exporting the current one and then compare it outside IntelliJ; with git or whatever.

Comment: This almost certainly means the file was downloaded incorrectly. Please verify your file by opening